# 8086 assembly program to store unique values

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, masm

I've been making this program that takes a list and finds unique elements in it and stores it in another list or register

the code below takes the main list into SI register and then BX acts as a pointer that walks through the whole array to find the similarities...if no similarities found the element in SI(which is stored in AL) gets stored in DI.. to avoid the first similarity that may occur when BX gets to the exact same location of it's value I set up a flag for that.

```
uniqueElement macro list1 list2
    local loop1,comparasionLabel,checkFlag,trigger,nextElement,addElement,endAddition
    lea si,list1
    lea di,list2 
loop1:
    mov ah,00H
    mov cx,00H   ;this is an intial flag gets triggered when an initial similarity is spotted
    lea bx,list1  ; this will be the search loop which will compare each of it's elements to SI
    mov al,BYTE PTR[SI] 
    cmp al,'$'  ; since I'm using a '$' terminated string
        je endAddition
comparasionLabel:
    mov dl,BYTE PTR[BX]
    cmp dl,'$'
        je addElement
    cmp al,dl
        je checkFlag
    inc bx
    jmp comparasionLabel    
            
checkFlag:           
    cmp cx,00H    ; this is when a first similarity is spotted, the flag gets triggered here
        je trigger
    cmp cx,01H       ; or if it was already triggered and another similarity spotted, SI moves to next element
        je nextElement     
trigger:
    mov cx,01H
    inc bx
    jmp comparasionLabel
nextElement:
    inc si
    jmp loop1
addElement:
    mov ah,00h
    mov BYTE PTR [di],al
    inc di
    inc si
    jmp loop1        
        
endAddition:
    inc di
    mov ah,00H
    mov al,'$'
    mov BYTE PTR[di],al               
endm
```

this is just the code that'll execute the macro

```
.model small
.data
list1 db 'H3llo$'    
list2 db 50 DUP [?]
.code  
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
uniqueElement list1 list2
mov ah,09H
mov dx,offset di
int 21h

.exit
```

and I have no Idea why it keeps printing the same list without removing the unique items

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Single step and see where it diverges from your expectations.

Comment: yes everything seemed woriking nice...but I guess that when an element is added it adds the entire list instead for some reason

Comment: Potentially searching through the entire source string for each character doesn't seem very efficient. A better approach might be to search through the destination string instead. Or if you expect the source strings to be fairly long, then it may be worth keeping a table with 128 entries where you keep track if a given character has been found or not.

Comment: didn't get the table part...could you please explain it more?

Comment: Have a table with 128 values (or 256 if you want to support extended ASCII), initially all set to 0 / false. For each character `ch` in the source string, if `table[ch]` is 0 / false, append `ch` to the destination string and set `table[ch` to 1 / true. This has some overhead because you need to clear the table at the beginning, but determining whether a character should be copied becomes a constant-time operation, so it might be worth it if you expect your source strings to be long.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the same list node in two different lists?  If single step isn't working for you then dump the state (the data structures & global variables, i.e. both lists).  Btw, debugging algorithms in assembly is super hard when first learning assembly.  I recommend doing your pseudo code in C, make sure it really works by testing it, then take that to assembly -- then guaranteed that mistakes are pure assembly errors, not algorithm design flaws.

Comment: @ErikEidt I think the whole issue is a storing issue in the first place....like he al gets moved to di after it was in si the value stored is the entire list instead of one element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and I have no Idea why it keeps printing the same list without removing the unique items

> ```
> mov ah,09H
> mov dx,offset di
> int 21h
> ```

The error is in the printing. The instruction `mov dx,offset di` is not correct! I would not be surprised if it would make MASM load the `DX` register will zero, and because the source text is at offset address zero, the outcome would be:

> ```
> h3llo
> ```

The correct code is the following:

```
mov  dx, offset list2
mov  ah, 09h
int  21h
```

---

The rest of the code is correct except for an extraneous `inc di` that introduces one garbage character in the output string right before the terminating "$".

---

Below is my rewrite of your algorithm, removing a lot of redundancies.
I have taken an alternative approach because rather than **flagging** similarities, I **count** matches. Each unique character will produce a single match, and so a character is added to the output buffer only if the counter has `CX=1`.

```
    lea  si, list1
    lea  di, list2 
loop1:
    mov  al, [si] 
    cmp  al, '$'
    je   endAddition

    xor  cx, cx       ; Counts matches, will become at least 1
    lea  bx, list1
loop2:
    inc  bx
    mov  dl, [bx-1]
    cmp  dl, '$'
    je   maybeAddElement
    cmp  al, dl
    jne  loop2
    inc  cx
    jmp  loop2

maybeAddElement:
    cmp  cx, 1
    jne  nextElement
    mov  [di], al
    inc  di
nextElement:
    inc  si
    jmp  loop1        
        
endAddition:
    mov  [di], al      ; AL='$'
```

Comment: There's a lot you could do to reduce the average time-complexity, e.g. when you find matches, cross them out with some other sentinel value.  So if there are 10 `'a'` characters in a string, on seeing the first `'a'` you loop over the *rest* of the array and zero out the others.  So you never have to check before the current read position for duplicates, and you only ever scan the rest of the array for duplicates once per unique char, not for every repeat.  Not as cheap as a histogram, but needs no extra space.

Comment: (To make this non-destructive for the src, you could start with strcpy into the destination, and record the length, then you can use `$` as the cross-out character because you now have the length, and can use that as the loop bound instead of a terminator.  Assuming the destination is large enough to hold the whole source temporarily.)

Comment: @Sep Roland your code works and mine worked too after removing the whole BYTE PTR thing and of course after replacing `` offset di `` with `` offset list2 `` ....I don't know why regarding the BYTE PTR thing but thanks so much for explaining the rest of my mistakes and for the alternative algorithim